# Trying to read the content of a text file (containing integers and characters) and storing it as different variables?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a txt file and store the content as variables. But the problem is that the txt file can have different contents. like for example,

txt1:

> 2 5000
>
> P 900 15 200 L(1) 300 U(1) 400
>
> A 2 10 500

txt2:

> 4 5000
>
> P 350 81 10 L(1) 90 U(1) 300
>
> P 500 50 100 L(5) 90 L(4) 90 L(3) 90 U(3) 90 U(4) 10 U(5) 100
>
> A 1 90 500
>
> A 7 93 50 L(1) 100 U(1) 300

So i have written a code that considers the following assumption,
line starting with 'A' has 3 parameters and with 'P' has 7 as in example 1. I do not know how to convert it to be generic.

The code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct specs
{
    int ttime,priority,iter1,iter_lock,iter_unlock,event;
    char lock_num[4];
    char unlock_num[4];
    char unlockid,lockid;
}obj[100];

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    int num_thread,time;
    char t[200];
    ifstream in("data.txt");
    if ( !in )
    {
    cout << "Error: Can't open the file named data.txt.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    in >> num_thread;
    in >> time;
    cout << "Number of threads = "<< num_thread << endl ;
    cout << "Total time is = " << time << endl;
    for (k = 0; k < num_thread;k++)
    {
        in >> t[k];
        if (t[k] == 'A')
        {
            in >> obj[k].event;
            in >> obj[k].priority;
            in >> obj[k].iter1;
            cout << obj[k].iter1<<endl;
        }
        else if (t[k] == 'P' )
        {
            in >> obj[k].ttime;
            in >> obj[k].priority;
            in >> obj[k].iter1;
            in >> obj[k].lock_num;
            in >> obj[k].iter_lock;
            in >> obj[k].unlock_num;
            in >> obj[k].iter_unlock;
            cout << obj[k].unlock_num<<endl;
            cout << obj[k].iter_lock<<endl;
            obj[k].unlockid = obj[k].unlock_num[2];
            obj[k].lockid = obj[k].lock_num[2];
            cout<< obj[k].unlockid <<endl;
            cout<< obj[k].lockid <<endl;
            int xx = obj[k].unlockid - '0';
            cout << xx<<endl;
        }

        else cout << " Invalid parameter";
    }
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "generic" in what sense? Also, C ***XOR*** C++? Pick one.

Comment: I  mean , each line may have as many parameters as it can. The one i have written assumes it to be fixed. I have written in c++. would be glad if i can get a solution in c++.

Comment: @userXXX Then you want a dynamic array, which, in C++, is most commonly realized using an `std::vector`.

Comment: Can u elaborate on how to use vectors ? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @userXXX You will have to read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @H2CO3 - Are you getting fed up that people tag both C and C++? I am

Comment: @EdHeal Me too. Definitely. Too bad that the automatic tag suggestion seems to support this (bad) idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, each with varying levels of complexity depending on what you want to do with the data.

Given the constraints of your data, I assume that at some point **you wish to parse the numeric items into numbers and the string items into strings.**

However, as your input isn't fixed and the type (string or int) vary in ordering, this is potentially problematic.

One way is to **use the whitespace to your advantage and tokenize the data into strings, then parse the tokens to determine if they are strings or numbers, and store them accordingly in their own separate containers.**

To that end, I've done the first part of breaking the file and lines into tokens and storing and outputting them in the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename = "txt1.txt";
    string temp;//a temporary variable used to store string data

    vector < vector <string> > tokens;
    vector < vector <string> >::iterator it;//used to iterate over `tokens`
    //used to iterate over the individual elements of `token`
    vector <string>::iterator jt;

    //initialize the `ifstream` object with the filename
    ifstream ifile(filename.c_str());

    //check to see if the file opened correctly
    if (ifile.is_open()) {
        //the file has been opened, now operate on it
        //by parsing over it and breaking each constituent line
        //into tokens:
        while(getline(ifile, temp)) {

            //initialize the string stream with the line that
            //was stored with getline:
            istringstream iss(temp);

            //this is a temporary vector to store the tokens per line
            vector <string> tokens_in_line;

            //use the whitespace to your advantage by using the
            //extraction operator to parse over the tokens
            //in each line and store them in the temporary vector (above)
            while(iss >> temp) {
                tokens_in_line.push_back(temp);
            }

            //at this point we may or may not have data in the temporary
            //vector. Check to see if its empty, if so reject storing it
            if (!tokens_in_line.empty()) {
                tokens.push_back(tokens_in_line);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cerr << "There was an error opening the input file!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ifile.close();

    //now output the information:
    for (it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it) {
        for (jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt) {
            cout << *jt << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All you have to do at this point is figure out how to store the data for the strings and numbers in their own separate containers for later access. While that may seem daunting, if you follow my comments, it should be easy to figure out *what to do* and *where* to do it.

UPDATE:

Regarding parsing the string tokens for the integer numbers, you can do something like this for those tokens (I've implemented it this way, as it's possible that the integer can be greater than a single digit):

```
std::string numbers = "0123456789";
std::string token = "L(1)";

std::size_t begin = token.find_first_of(numbers.c_str());
std::size_t end = token.find_last_of(numbers.c_str());

std::string num_str = input2.substr(begin, end-1);

std::cout << num_str << std::endl;
```

All you have to do at this point is convert the `num_str` value to an integer. There's one caveat to this though: it assumes that the numbers are contiguous and occur only once - otherwise, you'll have problems.

Comment: This works fine. Giving me the contents of the file.But when a particular token is read, it can be either a number or a set characters as shown. I need a way to determine what it is and based on that decision, store it in appropriate integer or char containers.

Comment: @Sherlock: correct. My version only stores everything as strings, but I left it up to you to determine how to determine if a token is a number or not so you could also gain something from the exercise. Hint: it's fairly trivial using stringstreams.

Comment: can u clarify on how i can access each and every token?

Comment: @Sherlock: in this section: `while (iss >> temp) { tokens_in_line.push_back(temp); }`, this is where the tokens in each line (string or int) is read and then stored. This is the best place to parse and store the different types. Similarly, for the `tokens` vector, this is a vector of vectors (2-dimensional). As such, each index contains a vector, which in turn holds the tokens for a given line.

Comment: I was able to identify between int and strings and store them . But the problem now is from the terms L(1) L(3) etc i just need to store the numbers separately. So when i use atoi(temp[2].c_str()) it produces an error as follows,../str.cpp:84:38: error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘temp.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(2ul)’, which is of non-class type ‘char’

Comment: @Sherlock: Had I known that this was what you had intended, I would have offered a different and more rigorous solution. However, consult the update that I posted in the above to guide you to what you should do next, and that should suffice nicely.